# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE in Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, adb, galaxy-nexus

Once again the same question about INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE. I searched stackoverflow and I can resume what is happening to me:

I have a Galaxy Nexus, fresh installed 4.3 directly from Google. I enabled the debug mode (clicking over version) and screen always on when connected. Set USB debugging on. I disabled verify  installed apps, both in development options and security.
The device is not rooted, but it is unlocked.
There is space in the cellphone (about 10GB free). The app works in emulator. I tried to run `adb shell su` but it doesn't work (not rooted, of course).

My questions:
Is really necessary to have your device rooted to debug android applications? I never had to do this with my old 2.3 Motorola Defy. What did change since 2.3 and what can I do to have this solved without rooting my device?

**EDIT**

I cannot list the contents of `data/local` (using `$ ls`) to certify there is no other version previously installed and corrupted. I cannot install the app using `adb install` (same error as in Eclipse). I tried in two different Windows 7 x64 computers and it doesn't work in any of them. Both computers are authorized when I first connected the device to them. In one of the computers, the adb version is 1.0.31. For the other computer I cannot verify right now.

Comment: Not sure what root access has to do with your problem. Do check if you are using an IDE where the app is going to be installed as I have been mistaken when running an emulator and a physical device at the same time. If you are still having problems, check that you can install via adb command line and add what was done in your question.

Comment: When you plugged it in to the PC the first time did it give you a pop-up on the phone asking you to verify the identity of the other computer?

Comment: also what version of the adb binary are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Caching Problem**

Android has its cache partition, try using Clean Master, or manualy clear all chace using Aplication Manager and cleaning broswer cache, i had same problem, and for google play works too! Try increasing ADT memory, click Perferences, Launch and add -partition-size 2048M in Default emulation options